How to fix this error in a flutter app? "[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()"
I am making a chatting app by following a Udemy tutorial. I can't seem to find the solution to this error that has been occuring and other solutions on stackoverflow either don't seem to work or I don't know how to implement them in my own code. The problem lies in my registration screen, the code is attached below
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../components.dart';
import 'chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'registration_screen';
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String email;
  late String password;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: 'logo',
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(text: 'Enter your email', onChanged: (value){email = value;},obscure: false,),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(text: 'Enter your password', onChanged: (value){password=value;},obscure: true,),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24.0,
            ),
            CustomButton(color: Colors.blueAccent, title: 'Register', onPressed: ()async{
              try{
                final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                print(newUser);
              }
              catch(e){
                print(e);
              }
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I asked chatGPT to solve this problem and it came up with a code that also didn't work:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../components.dart';
import 'chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'registration_screen';

  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String email;
  late String password;

  // Future to handle Firebase initialization
  late Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Once complete, show the application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Hero(
                    tag: 'logo',
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 200.0,
                      child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 48.0,
                  ),
                  CustomTextField(
                    text: 'Enter your email',
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      email = value;
                    },
                    obscure: false,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 8.0,
                  ),
                  CustomTextField(
                    text: 'Enter your password',
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      password = value;
                    },
                    obscure: true,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 24.0,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    title: 'Register',
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email,
                          password: password,
                        );
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I followed the code from a tutorial I was following, which perhaps might be outdated. I was expecting for the screen to at least load, but as soon as the user goes to the registration screen the app crashes and shows the error mentioned above.

Have you tried following the documentation?  That should always stay up to date.

initialize firebase in the main function like this
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

